# How to list popular resources in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I want to show all the featured resources like this:

[image]

How would I implement it neatly or maybe there could be some gem for the purpose?

Comment: You need to explain what the logic is behind deciding what to feature.

Comment: also, the examples you've used kind of suggest that you want to show a load of random crap on your website, like so many other crappy websites.

Comment: @MaxWilliams What kind of logic would you require to decide to feature posts? It seems to me that it doesn't matter.

Comment: If the question is "Given that i have already decided which resources i want to feature, then how do i display them like this?" then i agree.  it's not obvious to me that that is actually the case.  The question is very vague and might actually be asking how to decide which ones to feature in the first place.

Comment: More to the point, what is your actual question? "How would i implement it" is too vague.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I consider listing posts depending on the reviewed number. The very first logic that popped in my head was to count number of reviews. For example, when someone clicks on the link and goes on ceratin post it's considered as 1 review.

Comment: I'm still not hearing an actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a way of indicating that a post is 'popular' or 'featured'. A simple way is to add a boolean attribute to the post model. You can then create a scope.

```
class Post
  def self.featured
    where(featured: true)
  end
end
```